# How to fix wine apps that have a white background in unity tray

Tags: unity, wine, icons, system-tray

Many Wine apps and also some Java apps like Evernote or JDownloader appears in Unity tray with an annoying white background.

Is there a way to solve this issue?

Here is a screenshot about it: 
[image: Annoying white background of Evernote in Unity tray]

Comment: After posting this unanswered question (with no comments) 5+ years ago, OP signed on the next day and then hasn't been seen since. As this is about Ubuntu 12.04 or earlier which are all EOL, I'm VTC as `not reproducible`.